# Converting a number from one language to another - Google Input Tools, Excel

Tags: excel, google-input-tools

I have a database in Excel with numbers written in Hindi using Google Hindi Input. Is there any way I can change those to English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to change is to create a cell with English number and copy its format to all the cells. (Shortcut : Alt - E - S - T - Enter)